# A general theorem about state operators as a convex set?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator, quantum-states

I am trying to convince myself of a general theorem which fully "defines" the set of state operators. It is easy to prove that any convex combination of valid state operators is also a valid state operator (using the linearity of the trace), but I am looking for some converse which captures the notion that non-convex combinations of valid state operators are not valid state operators.

I was thinking something along the lines of

> An operator is a valid state operator $\rho$ if and only if it can be written only as some convex combination of valid state operators $\rho^{(i)}$:
> $$\rho = \sum a_i\rho^{(i)}; a_i \in [0,1], \sum a_i = 1.$$

but this is a little bit ugly. The "if" is the easy direction as mentioned above. I include the "only" since I am trying to exclude the possibility that it can be written both as a convex combination and as a nonconvex combination.

Any help in clarifying my thoughts/making this characterization precise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147814/discussion-on-question-by-ee18-a-general-theorem-about-state-operators-as-a-conv); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: The way you phrase it this is vacuous, as you haven't defined what a "valid state operators $\rho^{(i)}$"  are. (Otherwise, just choose a single $a_i$, $a_1=1$, and you have $\rho=\rho$, which is obviously both true and meaningless.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch By “valid” I am referring to the usual three axioms of unit trace, self-adjointness, and non-negativity.

Comment: Ok, then: If you write *"if it can be written only as"*, what does the "only" refer to? Which property should not be violated -- the convex combination? the $\rho^{(i)}$ being valid state operators?

Comment: Quoting from by chat with TobiasFunke, after some discussion there it was made clear to me that my question was really "I think my question is basically 1) can every density operator be expressed as a convex combination (the answer is yes per the eigendecomposition) and 2) must every such decomposition be convex (the answer is no)". No worries on this front -- my apologies, I should have had it closed but I'm not sure how to do that without deleting it (and perhaps it might be useful to someone else in the future)? @NorbertSchuch

Comment: I think the right way would have been to write an answer yourself.

Comment: Got it, will do that next time! @NorbertSchuch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incorrect.

E.g., the maximally mixed state of a qubit can also be written as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\tfrac12 \\ & \tfrac12\end{pmatrix} = 
a_1\begin{pmatrix}\tfrac23 \\ & \tfrac13\end{pmatrix} +
a_2\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ & 0\end{pmatrix} 
$$
with $a_1=\tfrac32$ and $a_2=-\tfrac12$, which is a non-convex-combination of valid density operators.